# Can't set Marker alpha value on Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, marker

I am trying to create a marker, but I simply can't call the [setAlpha(float alpha)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setAlpha%28float%29) method. This method does not appear on my list of callable methods on Eclipse. What should I do to set the alpha?

Here is my code:

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
markers.add(map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                     .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon)))
                                     .title(data + " " + overallList.get(4).get(1))
                                     .snippet((new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(timeIterator.next()))).toString())
                                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_circle_map))
                          )
            );
```

And here are the correspondent imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptionsCreator;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are not using the latest version of client library.

Update Google Play Services in Android SDK.

If using Gradle, make sure your dependency is at least 4.0.30.

Otherwise delete old google-play-services in your workspace and copy newest from extras/google folder.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. There was a recent release (a week ago). I updated Google Play Services using the Android SDK Manager and then I updated the reference to the new lib.

Comment: To check, which version is installed check your `AndroidManifest.xml` in `android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`